# What does it mean "not supported by HTML5"?

Tags: html

I am learning on w3schools and it says that for some of the attributes, it is not supported by HTML5. Does that mean I shouldn't learn it/there's no point in learning it?

Comment: It means exactly what it says, which is that it's not supported in HTML5. Whether you should learn it or not is up to you; you may not always be dealing with HTML5, because there are billions of web pages and trillions of HTML code samples and snippets that aren't compliant with HTML5. Do you want to be able to understand them when you read them or not?

Comment: Off topic but on point - w3Schools is adequate for many things - but is not always accurate in its content. Before accepting a thing as fact from that source alone - always research on your own and gather information from a number of different sources.

Comment: Typically, it means that the attribute is classified as [*obsolete*](http://w3c.github.io/html/obsolete.html#obsolete) by the HTML5 spec and therefore you should not use it in your web pages. Note that just because it is obsolete does not mean that browsers do not implement long standing functionality triggered by that attribute. In fact, the HTML5 spec often describes in detail what browsers should do when they encounter such attributes.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** it means in future these tags will not be supported and not recommended currently.

Don't use at all, rather use **CSS Or Alternative Tags**.

**Some Famous Tags:** not supported by HTML5

- "abbr" tag instead of "acronym" tag.
- "Applet" changed with "embed" or "object" tag.
- "center" tag with css properties.
- "Font" with css properties.
- "Strike" for giving strike to text is replaced with css properties.

**Other Are:** caption, iframe, img, input, object, legend, table, hr, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, col, colgroup, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead and tr table and object and the list goes on...